# Change PDF File name while Print - Save as action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I am showing PDF file in iframe window and my next action is print that iframe using javascript.  file is getting opened in print window but after click - save as PDF default option in print window, it shows actionname( method name) **DownloadReport** as file name in window dialog. I have to show different file name in windows dialog. here I am printing employee pdf report and I have to set file name as employeeId. how to do that?

below is javascript code of print-

```
$('#printFrame').attr('src', "/Employee/DownloadReport?id=" + empid + "&isEmp=" + flag + "&act=print");

            $('#printFrame').load(function () {
                
                window.frames['frm'].focus();
                window.frames['frm'].print();
                
                
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method to return Pdf response

```
   private FileResult ExportDocument(byte[] document, string format, string fileName, bool isInline)
        {
            string contentType;
            string disposition = (isInline) ? "inline" : "attachment";

            switch (format.ToLower())
            {
                case "docx":
                    contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                    break;
                case "xls":
                    contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                case "xlsx":
                    contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    break;
                case "mht":
                    contentType = "message/rfc822";
                    break;
                case "html":
                    contentType = "text/html";
                    break;
                case "txt":
                case "csv":
                    contentType = "text/plain";
                    break;
                case "png":
                    contentType = "image/png";
                    break;

                case "Jpeg":
                    contentType = "image/Jpeg";
                    break;
                default:
                    contentType = String.Format("application/{0};charset=utf-8", format);
                    break;
            }

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename={1}", disposition, fileName));
            return File(document, contentType);
        }
```

You can use it like

```
return ExportDocument(fromFileOrMemoryStream.ToArray(), "pdf", "myCustomReportName", true);
```

Comment: you didn't get my question.  am facing problem in print window action. when click save as pdf - file name is coming as actionname/methodname. I want diff. file name in window dialog to save file.

Comment: i got you bro, look at the solution you'll find it :)

Comment: its not working. I tried your approach. it still shows methodname as file name in window dialog when clicking save as option in print window.